I can't figure out what is wrong with my output to the program perftree
I am building a chess engine and I am trying to test it using this program I've used before called perftree. In order to get perftree to work with my code I need to format my output in a certain way. Here is the relevant section of the perftree readme file:

Your perft script
perftree requires some way to invoke the perft function on your chess
engine. Currently, it expects the user to provide a script, which will be
invoked like this:
./your-perft.sh "$depth" "$fen" "$moves"

where

$depth is the maximum depth of the evaluation,

$fen is the [Forsyth-Edwards Notation][fen] string of some base position,

$moves is an optional space-separated list of moves from the base position
to the position to be evaluated, where each move is formatted as
$source$target$promotion, e.g. e2e4 or a7b8Q.


The script is expected to output the results of the perft function to standard
output, with the following format:

For each move available at the current position, print the move and the
number of nodes at the given depth which are an ancestor of that move,
separated by whitespace.

After the list of moves, print a blank line.

Finally, print the total node count on its own line.


For example, this is what the depth-3 perft of the starting position should look
like:
$ ./your-perft.sh 3 "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
a2a3 380
b2b3 420
c2c3 420
d2d3 539
e2e3 599
f2f3 380
g2g3 420
h2h3 380
a2a4 420
b2b4 421
c2c4 441
d2d4 560
e2e4 600
f2f4 401
g2g4 421
h2h4 420
b1c3 440
g1h3 400
b1a3 400
g1f3 440

8902


I have gotten my code to output something similar. Here is my code:
let mut move_options = Vec::new();
game.generate_moves(&mut move_options, &all_move_data);
let mut total_nodes = 0;

let mut log_file = OpenOptions::new().create(true).append(true).open("perftree_output.log").expect("failed to open log file");
let mut output = String::new();
for game_move in move_options {
    let move_nodes = count_nodes(depth, &game_move, &game, &all_move_data);
    total_nodes += move_nodes;
    output.push_str(&format!("{} {}\n", game_move, move_nodes));
    //println!("{} {}", game_move, move_nodes);
}

output.push_str("\n");
output.push_str(&format!("{}\n", total_nodes));
//println!("{}", output);
output = output.trim().to_string();
write!(io::stdout(), "{}", output).expect("failed to write to stdout");
write!(log_file, "{}", output).expect("failed to write to log");

and its output to the log file when using perftree:
a2a3 20
b2b4 20
b2b3 20
c2c4 20
c2c3 20
d2d4 20
d2d3 20
e2e4 20
e2e3 20
f2f4 20
f2f3 20
g2g4 20
g2g3 20
h2h4 20
h2h3 20
b1a3 20
b1c3 20
g1f3 20
g1h3 20

400

It looks right to me, but perftree says

cannot compute diff: invalid digit found in string

I cannot figure out why perftree is seeing an invalid digit in that output. I don't think it is a problem with perftree, because I have used it before and it worked great.
Here is a bash script that should output exactly what perftree expects no matter the input:
#!/bin/bash
echo "a2a4 20"
echo "a2a3 20"
echo "b2b4 20"
echo "b2b3 20"
echo "c2c4 20"
echo "c2c3 20"
echo "d2d4 20"
echo "d2d3 20"
echo "e2e4 20"
echo "e2e3 20"
echo "f2f4 20"
echo "f2f3 20"
echo "g2g4 20"
echo "g2g3 20"
echo "h2h4 20"
echo "h2h3 20"
echo "b1a3 20"
echo "b1c3 20"
echo "g1f3 20"
echo "g1h3 20"
echo
echo "400"

I tried this and it still didn't work.

I removed all of the println! statements elsewhere in the code, and made sure it is not panicking when I pass the inputs perftree passes to the program. I also fixed all of the warnings so they wouldn't be considered outputs and I am using the executable from target/release so I don't get build messages from cargo.

"invalid digit found in string" is precisely what a Rust would output if it unwrap'd the result of integer parsing. Are you sure the error is from perftree, or could perftree be forwarding an error from your script? (edit: perftree is also a Rust program, so this is not conclusive)

I checked perftree's source code and your implementation and couldn't find any problems. I suspect there is some issue I can't see, so I recommend publishing a reproducible example as opposed to a snippet of your script.

If I tried to post all of my code it would surpass the character limit. Here is the github page: https://github.com/Name806/RICE

Thanks! Is this the corresponding part?

Actually I pushed my code after I posted the link, so the code I tried to use with perftree is now pushed to origin main. That is the old version.

Please [edit] your code so it includes a minimal reproducible example within the question, not behind an external link.

Ah, I understand, Here is a script that should output what perftree expects: #!/bin/bash echo "a2a4 20" echo "a2a3 20" echo "b2b4 20" echo "b2b3 20" echo "c2c4 20" echo "c2c3 20" echo "d2d4 20" echo "d2d3 20" echo "e2e4 20" echo "e2e3 20" echo "f2f4 20" echo "f2f3 20" echo "g2g4 20" echo "g2g3 20" echo "h2h4 20" echo "h2h3 20" echo "b1a3 20" echo "b1c3 20" echo "g1f3 20" echo "g1h3 20" echo echo "400" I tried this and it doesn't work either.

I realize that doesn't show up well in a comment so I edited my original question with the script.

Just FYI that there is a better tool for splitperft testing: https://analog-hors.github.io/webperft/

I figured it out! There was no problem with my code. The problem was with stockfish. I found out on the perftree github page that its last commit was 3 years ago. So I downloaded stockfish 13, which came out before the last commit, and it works!
